# Solution to difference differential equation with constant coefficients

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, pr.probability

This problem arose when solving a continuous Markov chain exercise from a book I am studying. Given a set of positive $q_i$ with $i \in \mathbb{Z} $, and non-negative $\lambda$ and $\mu$ that add to 1, the solution amounts to solving

$p_{0,i}'(t) = \lambda q_{i-1} p_{0,i-1}(t) - q_i p_{0,i}(t) + \mu q_{i+1} p_{0,i+1}(t) \;\; \text{where} \; \;  i \in \mathbb{Z}$

with initial conditions $p_{0,i}(0) = \delta_{0,i}$. How does one go about solving this problem?

Comment: Try to write it in a vector-matrix form, then you should see it immediately.

Comment: @abatkai Unfortunately I am not understanding how this helps. The solution to this difference differential equation is 0-th row of matrix exponential of a tri-banded matrix, `$p_{0,i}(t) = (exp(t*Q))_{0,i}$`, where `$Q$` is zero except for $Q_{i,i+1}=\lambda q_i$, $Q_{i,i}=-q_i$ and $Q_{i,i-1} = \mu q_i$. Then the question gets rephrased into how does compute matrix exponential of this matrix ? I am sure this is a standard topic, so a pointer to a book, or web-article will be sufficient. 

Comment: confluential: you say: "The solution to this difference differential equation is 0-th row of matrix exponential..."

Therefore, why are you asking this question on MO? Why don't you directly ask "How do we compute exp(M) for a tri-banded matrix M" or similar (after first trying to look it up yourself, of course; I'm sure almost every good numerical analysis book will discuss this at length).

Comment: @(Zen Harper) Because I am seeking a symbolic solution. I was hoping that reformulating of it in terms of difference-differential equation will lead to results faster. After all, I only need to compute `$p_{0,i}(t)$` and not `$p_{j,i}(t)$`. Maybe I failed to make it more explicit, but the matrix  `$Q$` is infinite dimensional, so this may be a substantial simplification for exponentiation of the entire matrix.

Comment: Basically, your problem looks like a spatial finite difference discretization of a heat equation with (spatially) variable coefficients. You should not expect a closed form solution unless $q_i$ is independent of $i$.

Comment: I was hoping that the solution be expressible as an infinite series of exponentials. 

Comment: Keywor: inhomogeneous birth and death process. 
For general $q_i$ there is no real hope for simple symbolic solutions. There is a representation of the following kind: 
Orthogonal polynomials on the real line can be characterized by a three term recurrence relation. You can find a set of orthogonal polynomials to the coefficients $q_i$ wrt. to a positive regular measure $\psi$. Then the solution $p_{ij}(t)$ has an integral representation of this orthogonal polynomials wrt. to the measure $\psi$. For reference see: Karlin and McGregor: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1992942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Renardy for the analogy with the heat equation. Let's assume $q_i = q$, i.e. independent on $i$. The difference-differential equation can then be solved by using generating function technique. Let $G(z) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} z^i p_{0,i}(t)$. Then the equation and initial condition imply that $G(z) = \exp(-q t) \exp \left( q t (\lambda z + \mu/z) \right)$. Extracting series coefficients from here gives: $p_{0,i}(t) = \exp(-q t) \lambda^{i/2} \mu^{-i/2} I_{i}( 2 q t \sqrt{\lambda \mu})$, which is known as [Skellam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) distribution.